# Python, object not supporting indexing

Tags: python

I'm extracting data from `Y!F` using `yahoo_finance` module. A type error:

> 'Share' object does not support indexing

is occurring.

Any ideas?

```
import yahoo_finance
from yahoo_finance import Share

class ticker(object):
    def __init__(self, symbol):

        self.price = symbol.get_price()
        self.change = symbol.get_change()
        self.volume = symbol.get_volume()

symbol = ['GOOG','AAPL','MSFT']

lenSymbol = len(symbol)
cc = 0

while cc < lenSymbol:
    stringSymb = symbol[cc]
    symbol = Share(stringSymb) #TypeError occurring here
    c = ticker(symbol)
    output = ([c.volume, c.price, c.change, c.volume])
    print (output)
    cc += 1
```

Comment: Please provide the *full traceback*, not just the last line.

Comment: I'd bet the problem is shadowing the list `symbol = ['GOOG', ...]` with the `Share` instance `symbol = Share(...)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `symbol` twice:

```
symbol = ['GOOG','AAPL','MSFT']
```

And in the loop:

```
symbol = Share(stringSymb)
```

It seems that `Share` from `yahoo_finance` does not support indexing.

Try changing it to the following:

```
import yahoo_finance
from yahoo_finance import Share

class ticker(object):
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.price = symbol.get_price()
        self.change = symbol.get_change()
        self.volume = symbol.get_volume()

symbols = ['GOOG','AAPL','MSFT']

cc = 0
while cc < len(symbols):
    stringSymb = symbols[cc]
    symbol = Share(stringSymb)
    c = ticker(symbol)
    output = ([c.volume, c.price, c.change, c.volume])
    print (output)
    cc += 1
```

Output:

```
['11164943', '672.93', '+93.08', '11164943']
['46164710', '129.62', '+1.11', '46164710']
['29467107', '46.62', '-0.04', '29467107']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning your list `symbol` to:

```
symbol = Share(stringSymb)
```

then next loop, you are trying to index `symbol`

```
stringSymb = symbol[cc]
```

And as the error states, the `Share` object that you reassigned `symbol` to, does not support indexing.